# Need to return all columns from a table when using GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table let's say it has four columns
`Id, Name, Cell_no, Cat_id`.
I need to return all columns whose count of `Cat_id` is greater than `1`.

The group should be done on `Cell_no` and `Name`.
What i have done so far..

```
select Cell_no, COUNT(Cat_id)
from TableName
group by Cell_Number
having COUNT(Cat_id) > 1
```

But what i need is some thing like this.

```
select * 
from TableName
group by Cell_Number
having COUNT(Cat_id) > 1
```

Comment: I think you mean "return all *rows* whose count of Cat_id is greater than 1"?

Comment: yes but need to check that those columns have same Cell_no or name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pratik's answer is good but rather than using the `IN` operator (which only works for single values) you will need to `JOIN` back to the result set like this

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM tableName t
INNER JOIN      
    (SELECT Cell_no, Name 
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY Cell_no , Name
    HAVING COUNT(Cat_id) > 1) filter
    ON t.Cell_no = filter.Cell_no AND t.Name = filter.Name
```

Comment: Kirk Broadhurst,, IN operator works fine with multiple columns combination in oracle database .. 

pardon me .. I didn't check that whether same works in SQL SQRVER or not.. :)

Answer (score 1):

you just need to modify your query like below --

```
select * from tableName where (Cell_no, Name) in (
          select Cell_no, Name from TableName
           Group by Cell_no , Name
           having COUNT(Cat_id) > 1
           )
```

as asked in question you want to group by Cell_no and Name.. if so you need to change your query for group by columns and select part also.. as I have mentioned

Comment: Correct logic but the `IN` operator works for single values, not tuples.

Comment: In oracle you can apply and check the IN operator for multiple columns as well.. 

so that's why i wrote that ..

Comment: Thanks pratik, sorry I didn't mean to criticise just that it didn't work for me in TSQL. I haven't used Oracle in many years...

Answer (score 1):

This version requires only one pass over the data:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT a.*
              ,COUNT(cat_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cell_no)
               AS count_cat_id_not_null
        FROM   TableName a)
WHERE  count_cat_id_not_null > 1;
```

Comment: When I check this execution plan it contains 2 inner joins, compare with mine which contains 1 inner join. It's also 30% slower. I was surprised.

Comment: YMMV. I suspect your inner joins are over some indexes, yes?

Comment: Just noting that when I ran this on SQL 2008 R2 I needed to add an alias to the inner result set to execute.