# How to group by 1 column with select *

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

i'm currently struggling with an SQL task.

I have an select Statement like this

`SELECT * FROM data dt LEFT JOIN payment pm ON pm.month = dt.month AND pm.persID = dt.persID`

Two Colums of data table are relevant for the condition (data.department, pm.payout).

Now i need all Information grouped by department where payout = 0.

I tried first to simply group by department

`SELECT * FROM data dt LEFT JOIN payment pm ON pm.month = dt.month AND pm.persID = dt.persID GROUP BY dt.department`

But this error occurs: Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.

Then i tried it with first checking if the payout is 0.

`SELECT * FROM data dt LEFT JOIN payment pm ON pm.month = dt.month AND pm.persID = dt.persID WHERE pm.payout = 0`

Comment: since you don't have any aggregate values, you might want to just sort instead. Try `ORDER BY dt.department` instead of `GROUP BY`

Comment: @tnavidi tried and worked. But how would it be possible to just group by the department. For example if I sum(payout)

Comment: you need to group by all the columns you have in your select part (except the sum(payout). That means you need to list all the columns from both tables in your group by (that includes pm.month and dt.month even if they're the same). A better choice is to specify each column you actually need in the select rather than using `select *`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to return all columns from a table when using GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780195/need-to-return-all-columns-from-a-table-when-using-group-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mention column name with SELECT to use GROUP BY. i.e.

```
SELECT dt.department FROM data dt
JOIN payment pm ON pm.month = dt.month AND pm.persID = dt.persID
WHERE pm.payout = 0
GROUP BY dt.department
```

The above query will result only grouped departments.
Since you want all the columns you need to look at this question.
[Need to return all columns from a table when using GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780195/need-to-return-all-columns-from-a-table-when-using-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my answer is not grammatically correct, English is not my native language.

You have to put the arguments in the proper order.

[Link](https://intellipaat.com/blog/tutorial/sql-tutorial/order-by-group-by/)

I don't know what type of columns you have in the table, and what results you want to get. I mean, I don't know if you want to count() or sum() a column.

I have understood in your post that you only want to see the results in which 'payout=0'.

For example, With the information you provided, I would do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM data dt LEFT JOIN payment pm ON pm.month = dt.month AND pm.persID = dt.persID where pm.payout = 0 GROUP BY dt.department;
```

Have I helped you?

If not, give me more information to see what we can do.